# Algorithms to identify patterns between wav

Tags: java, algorithm, wav

im working on a project where  have to identify similar patterns between wave files where the frequency differ.
for a example the human voice frequency differs from each other. if i hv to identify if the human **crying , shouting laughter of a voice**, there should be a pattern between crying voices regardless to the frequency.

so im looking for a algorithm that can identify these elements.

Comment: One could write an entire book on analysing wave forms of the human voice. If you want good answers, you need to ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by taking a look at [Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network). These type of programs usually deal well with certain *inconsistencies* in your data. The [Neuroph Studio](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/) provides you with a quick and relatively easy way to construct your Neural Network.

All you need is a set of data containing whatever you want to match. You can use about 70% of this data to let your Neural Network learn to cluster your data and then, use the remaining 30% to test your Neural Network.

The main issue with Neural Networks is that you need to find a way to encode your data into input vectors. Once you do that, the Neural Network should try and learn to find the differences on its own.

Answer (score 0):

For Image based recognition Principal Component Analysis and it's siblings, like Kernel PCA or Linear Discriminent Analysis are the right thing. PCA is an algorithm which works on any kind of data, so I think also on sound.

I would convert the wav into int-Vectors and run an PCA on it to extract the features.

[JMathTools](http://jmat.sourceforge.net/_index.html) are very good for that...

this i found [also](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/912/is-there-an-analogous-library-to-opencv-for-audio-analysis)...

Hope i can helped you...